# Maximo inbound MIF automation script - Place failed message in error queue for Message Reprocessing

Tags: python, automation, integration, jython, maximo

I've made an Enterprise Service External Exit automation script that fires when a message is received.  Is there a way to send this message to Message Reprocessing if I run into some unknown error?  As it stands when the error occurs the process fails and the message is lost.

I know I can skip a message by setting the error group and key in my script like this to skip the transaction, is there something similar that redirects to the error queue instead?

```
errorgroup = "iface"
errorkey ="SKIP_TRANSACTION"
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just throw an error - message reprocessing will reprocess it (default 5 times) then it will be an error in the error queue. You will have to double check your queue configurations